# how to align html text using css when headings are different lengths

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some span tags which I am using to style some headings and some text on the same line.

However I want to style the text in the award class so that it is lined up after the length of the longest sub_heading (which is Date Awarded at 12 characters. Is there a javascript library or css trick to do this?

```
<span class="sub_heading">Award<span class="award">Award Name</span></span>
<span class="sub_heading">Date Awarded<span class="award">2009</span></span>
```

It would end up:

**Award:**..............Award Name (without periods obviously).

**Date Awarded:** 2009

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best thing to do is to change the markup, you can do that in multiple ways, this is an example:

**Example using tables**

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Award</td>
    <td>Award name</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date awarded</td>
    <td>2000</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your markup a bit you can use `display: table` to achieve this effect.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
}

.award {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row"><span class="sub_heading">Award</span><span class="award">Award Name</span></div>
  <div class="row"><span class="sub_heading">Date Awarded</span><span class="award">2009</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css or table to setup a layout. I think it is a easier way and has better performance. But I would also like to provide you with another way with javascript, and you can figure out which will be the best way for your case. Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/b8063z7c/
The main code is this:

```
(function() {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    $.each($(".sub_heading"), function() {
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).width());
    })

    $.each($(".sub_heading"), function() {
        $(this).css("padding-right", maxWidth - $(this).width());
    })
})();
```

Hope this will help.